# Adding items on a spinner using a cutom function in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do i add items to a spinner in a fragment using a custom method since i have many spinners and setting each on the create view makes the code have unprofessional looking

This is what i have tried but returns an error
I had also declared the provincespinner

```
  private Spinner provincespinner, districtspinner; 

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_basicinfo, container, false);
    addItemsOnProvinceSpinner(rootView);  //this is what i would like to add items

      ...i have other methods to add other spinners here

    return rootView;

}
```

This is the method that should add but returns an error

```
    public void addItemsOnProvinceSpinner(View rootview) {
        provincespinner = (Spinner) rootview.findViewById(R.id.fivms_farmerprovince);  
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("list 1");
        list.add("list 2");
        list.add("list 3");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list); //This returns an error
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
provincespinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

How do i go about this

Comment: pls post your error

Comment: The error is cannot resolve an constructor

Comment: I have updated the error location

Comment: Just change "this" by "getActivity" in your ArrayAdapter Initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your line like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new
ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

the first parameter is context and you are passing this which works for activity

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI glad to help you